# Elmah is sending multiple emails per error. Only remote port is different

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, elmah, elmah.mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 app and I am using ELMAH to only send emails.  It is sending me 2 emails per error, and the REMOTE PORT is different, but nothing else.  And, that PORT # is not the port my app is accessing.

For instance, I am using localhost port 55116

Error 1 port: 51467
Error 2 port: 51469

Why am I getting two emails, and how can I reduce it to one?